# Custom form not saved

Tags: controller, visualforce

Iam a newbe to APEX and I have the following form and Controller

```
<apex:page controller="AddLinesController">
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageMessages />
  <apex:form >
      <h1>Create Quote for "{!opportunity.Name}" with paste from seema.de</h1>
      <apex:inputHidden id="QuoteId" value="{!opportunity.Id}"/>
      <p>
          <label for="name">Quote Name</label>
          <br/>
          <apex:inputText value="{!name}" id="name" />
      </p>
      <p>
          <label for="paste">Paste from seema.de</label>
          <br/>
          <apex:inputTextarea id="paste" cols="55" rows="3"/>
      </p>
      <p>
         <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Create quote from paste"/>
         <a href="/{!opportunity.Id}">Cancel</a>
      </p>
      Value is: <b>{!name}</b>
  </apex:form>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

An the controller

```
public class AddLinesController {
    public String opportunityId;
    public String name;
    public String paste;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public Opportunity getOpportunity() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity
                WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('OpportunityId')];
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        Opportunity op = getOpportunity();

        Quote q = new Quote(Name=name, OpportunityId=op.Id);
        insert q;

        PageReference page = new ApexPages.StandardController(q).view();
        page.setRedirect(true);
        return page;
    }
}
```

So far the getOpportunity works fine but the setName does not work why?
Why it does not work?

Comment: So in `save()` your local property `name` is not set when you try to instantiate the Quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public String name;

public String getname() { //getters 
    return name;
}
public void setname(String name) { //setters 
    this.name = name;
}
```

try the above and this is the standard way of using getters and setters in apex.

Before your action methods all the setters will run and you can debug the variable in your save method

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
public String name;
public String getname() { //getters 
return name;
}
public void setname(String name) { //setters 
this.name = name;
}
```

we can rite get and setters directly

```
public String name{get;set;}
```